# How to turn String into another Type to use in a Function

Tags: java, android, android-layout, types

I have a string coming in from the network.

That string matches a variable.
The variable is of type FrameLayout.

I have a function that's called with a FrameLayout.

How do I get the function to accept the incoming string

```
   @InjectView (R.id.printer45)
   FrameLayout printer_45;       

   public static final List<String> RED = Arrays.asList("printer_45")

   redLabelIcon(FrameLayout fL){

    ***create red icon***

   }

   String printer = data.getString("Printer")
   String status = data.getString("Status")

   **turn printer into frameLayout, somehow**

       if (RED.contains(status)){
           redLabelIcon(printer)
         }
```

What is this that I am trying to do, so that I can research it.

Comment: Hi Sirvon, do you want to convert the printer string name to appropriate FrameLayout ? Also do you have multiple FrameLayouts injected in your class ? If that is that case you can use a simple if else loop to check if the string matches "A" use FrameLayout A else framelayout B. (factory pattern does similar thing by returning you the exact object based on your input which can be a string).

Comment: Yes, I want to convery string name to FrameLayout and for extra credit please instruct me on how to inject FrameLayout into class because I tried and had similar type problems.

Comment: if(printer.equals("layout1")) return Framelayout1 else return FrameLayout2 .. can you use something like this ?

Comment: can you make this an answer for clarity and fullness. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called a *mapping*:

```
Map<String, FrameLayout> mapping = new HashMap<>();
mapping.put("printer_45", printer_45);
```

In the same way you can put as many layouts as you want into that map under a String typed key. Later you retrieve layouts:

```
String printer = data.getString("Printer");
FrameLayout layout = mapping.get(printer);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is called "mapping" - usually you will see this with "key" / "value" pairs in a Hashtable, for example. Or you can use a `Map` or use a `case` statement or "else/if".

In your case, the `List` object does not have a "key" only a "value" so it does not work. You need to be able to associate a "key" like "RED" with a value like "printer_45".

If you used a `Hashtable` then do not use "RED" as the name of your object, use something like "printers" and then give "printer_45" as the "value" and "RED" as the key. You could also do this with a `Map` or two `Arrays` (one "key" and one "value") or many other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FactoryMethod pattern to get that

```
    public static FrameLayout getFrameLayout(String layoutName){
     if("layout1".equals(layoutName)){
      return FrameLayout1;
     }   else if (...){
     return FrameLayout2
     }
     ....
    }
```

Comment: but say i have like 100s of framelayouts...I have to keep using that if/else return pattern for 100s of lines?

Comment: I feel that you can not avoid mapping 100 framelayout names to framelayout objects. In that case i would suggest you to use a Map to store the key as framelayoutname and value as framelayout object.